# Which people get paid in Million Dollar Listing?

Tags: production, film-industry, million-dollar-listing

The reality TV series *Million Dollar Listing* shows a lot of people:

- the main real estate agents
- agents that they negotiate with
- agents who come to their open houses
- real estate developers
- clients and potential clients
- the agents' chauffeurs / drivers
- the agents' staff

Screen Actors Guild is very specific about how their members get paid, but since these people are not in SAG, those union rules don't apply. So which of these groups of people get paid by the show?

Comment: Doubtful if this is publically available. An "appearance fee" might be involved or perhaps those people like having their work publicised. Interesting!

Comment: @Paulie_D Another complication is that some of the people are stars (the agents), some are recurring (chauffeurs, staff, developers), and some may only be seen for a few seconds in one episode (open house guests).